# Can't find contacts in Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, contacts

I'm trying to restore lost contacts information from Time Machine. Where is the data stored on the HD? I've searched the Library, Documents and other likely places, but can't find the actual cards anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The Contacts database is stored in a single SQLite3 database per source. You can find a list of databases by running the following command:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook/ -name "AddressBook-v22.abcddb"
```

Comment: when I try to open the "AddressBook-v22.abcddb" file it does not work ?

Comment: @Buscar What are you trying to open it with? It's an SQLite3 database as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: my mistake, I tough I can see the actual contacts in there

Comment: @Buscar You can if you dump the contents: `sqlite3 /path/to/AddressBook-v22.abcddb .dump > ~/Desktop/export`